# Can't access token in Next.js API route

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, next-auth

**SOLUTION START**:

auth.js

```
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
        if (account) {
            token.accessToken = account.access_token
          }
          return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
        session.token = token.accessToken ?? "No token found";
        return session; // This will be available in server components
    },
    async redirect() {
        return "/";
    }
}
```

page.tsx:

```
export default async function Page() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
  const token = session?.token;
  return <pre>{session?.token}</pre>
}
```

next-auth-d.ts:

```
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";
import type { Session, Account,JWT } from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface JWT {
    accessToken?: accessToken;
    user: {
      token?: accessToken;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
  interface Session {
    token?: accessToken;
    user: {
      token?: accessToken;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
  interface Account {
    access_token: accessToken;
    user: {
      token?: accessToken;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION END**

### EDIT:
According to https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7423
This is the expected behaviour. However, how do i access the token in my server components?

I'm logging in using NextAuth with Azure AD as the provider, which works fine.

In the NextAuth callbacks, I receive the access_token.
In middleware.ts, I can use the `getToken(req, secret)` method and access the access_token.

However, in my internal API routes, the `getToken(req, secret)` always returns null.
req.cookies.getAll() also return nothing. I need my access_token either in my internal APIS or my Server Components.

Also in my my server components (which is where I prefer to use this token the most), I don't know how to access this token since the request object is not present there.

My AuthConfig:

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";
import { CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, TENANT_ID } from "./utils/envPublic";

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        AzureADProvider({
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
            tenantId: TENANT_ID,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    scope: "openid profile email api://myapi/my.scope",
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt"
    },
    jwt: {
        secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
            token.accessToken = account?.access_token;
            return { ...token, ...user, ...account };
        },
        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            session.token = token.accessToken;
            session.user.token = token.accessToken;
            return session;
        },
        async redirect() {
            return "/"
        }
    },

};

export default authOptions;
```

My API route:

```
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const GET = async (req: NextRequest) => {
    
    const token = await getToken({ req: req, secret: process.env.SECRET })
    console.log("token from API:")
    console.log(token); // this always returns null

    const cookies = req.cookies.getAll();
    console.log("cookies from API:")
    console.log(cookies.length); // this always returns 0

    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    const json = await response.json();

    return NextResponse.json(json);
}
```

My middleware.ts

```
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'
import type { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const token = await getToken({ req: request, secret: process.env.SECRET });
    console.log("token:");
    console.log(token); // This will log the correct token
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#in-app-directory

Comment: Well no, the token is null/undefined there. I must be doing something wrong in my authoptions. I think its extremely unclear what's actually going on there with the callbacks. account.access_token logs the real value, but i dont know how to pass it on so it can be used in my components.